# error: column "month" does not exist in PG query

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

My PG query:

```
SELECT "Tracks"."PageId", 
       date_trunc("month", "Tracks"."createdAt") AS month, 
       count(*) 
FROM "Tracks" 
WHERE "Tracks"."PageId" IN (29,30,31) 
GROUP BY month, "Tracks"."PageId"
```

and my schema:

`id, createdAt, updatedAt, PageId`

A bit confused as to why I'm receiving this error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an alias in the where or group by clause. You need to repeat the expression:

```
SELECT "Tracks"."PageId", 
       date_trunc('month', "Tracks"."createdAt") AS month, 
       count(*) 
FROM "Tracks" 
WHERE "Tracks"."PageId" IN (29,30,31) 
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', "Tracks"."createdAt"), "Tracks"."PageId";
```

Note that the first parameter for `date_trunc()` is a `varchar` value, so you need to put that in single quotes, not double quotes.

---

If you don't want to repeat the expression you can put that into a derived table:

```
select "PageId", month, count(*)
from (
    SELECT "Tracks"."PageId", 
           date_trunc('month', "Tracks"."createdAt") AS month
    FROM "Tracks" 
    WHERE "Tracks"."PageId" IN (29,30,31) 
) t
group by month, "PageId";
```

---

<sup>Unrelated, but: you should really avoid quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble then they are worth it</sup>

Comment: Thanks! For my own learning, and clarification, the reason this failed was because I had month in double quotes, not single quotes?